# Clustering nodes on a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, cluster-analysis

Say I have a weighted, undirected graph with X vertices. I'm looking separate these nodes into clusters, based on the weight of an edge between each connected vertex (lower weight = closer together).

I was hoping I could use an algorithm like K means clustering to achieve this, but it seems that K means requires data in at least a 2D space, while I only have the weights of each edge to go from.

Is there a way to cluster nodes of a weighted graph together? I don't have a preference as to whether I need to specify the number of clusters or not.

I suspect I'm missing something relatively simple here, but it is rather late.

I've considered whether I just need to traverse the graph, and for each node find its Y closest immediate neighbours, but that seems too simple.

**Edit:** Apologies: to be more specific: the graph isn't too large (around 150 vertices, maximum), and is not complete. I'm using Python.

Comment: Is your graph very big? Nodes? Edges? The simplest option I can think of is hierarchical clustering. You will need to go for minimum merge mode, as I guess your graph is not complete. What language do you use ? So I can suggest some libraries or packages.

Comment: You could compute the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree and treat this as a hierarchical clustering

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Community Detection in complete and weighted networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44899773/community-detection-in-complete-and-weighted-networks)

Comment: @Picarus, sorry. I've added more info to the question! The graph isn't complete, around ~150 vertices maximum, and I'm currently using Python.

Comment: @mcdowella, the minimum spanning tree would get me the subset of vertices that connect together so that every node on the graph is reached, correct? I think this would only get the nearest neighbour to each vertex, rather than the ~3 closest neighbours ,for example

Comment: @BnMcG The minimum spanning tree is equivalent to hierarchical clustering and it has good and bad features. You can convert it into clusters by removing the k largest links in the MST and treating the resulting connected components a clusters. Whether it is good for you depends on what you really want. A web search finds various pages talking about these features such as https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25725643 https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2009/cmsc451/lectures/Lec07a-mst.pdf

Comment: In Python, I would start with: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/algorithms.connectivity.html#module-networkx.algorithms.connectivity.cuts and other algorithms in the same page. Sorry for not having time to help you a bit more. I will try in the coming days to provide a more specific answer. If you look for solutions to problems like the karate club or Dolphins you may get some ideas. I used in the past genetic algorithms but is probably not what may help you most. Do you know how many clusters do you want to find? That is usually a difficult part of the problem.

Comment: @Picarus, I don't have any set number of clusters I want to find, I'm happy to (and I think the dataset would be small enough) that I could just try out a few different numbers of clusters and see what works, if needs be. Thank you both, your comments have been helpful!

Comment: Some other clustering methods that don't require the nodes to be points in a vector space are [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) (despite "spatial" in its name) and [K-medoids clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids).