# louvain community detection in complete weighted networks returns only 1 partition

Tags: python-3.x, graph, cluster-analysis, networkx

Referring to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44907357/305883

I am using python-louvain implementation to detect community in complete weighted graph.

But I only get one partition, containing all nodes.

Code:

```
import community # this is pip install python-louvain
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Replace this with your networkx graph loading depending on your format !

# using graph g as a completed graph, weights between 0 and 1

#first compute the best partition
partition = community.best_partition(g)

#drawing
size = float(len(set(partition.values())))
pos = nx.spring_layout(g)
count = 0.
for com in set(partition.values()) :
    count = count + 1.
    list_nodes = [nodes for nodes in partition.keys() if partition[nodes] == com]
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g, pos, list_nodes, node_size = 20, node_color = str(count / size))


nx.draw_networkx_edges(g, pos, alpha=0.1)

plt.show()
```

I would like to extract communities from a complete weighted network.

I also tried girvan_newman (https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-2.0/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.community.centrality.girvan_newman.html) but could only detect 2 communities out of a complete graph of 200 nodes (with 198 and 2 nodes).

Is Louvain working correctly to detect communities in complete graph?
Better suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure your weights are under the key `weight` in your graph? If you're performing Louvain on an unweighted complete graph it would logically return a single cluster.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the used model selection for this case returns a single block with all nodes, which means that there is not enough statistical evidence for more blocks.

You could try Peixotos [`graph-tool`](https://graph-tool.skewed.de) package, which has an implementation of [weighted stochastic block model](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.97.012306).

Comment: @sparsky05 (great nick sparsky by the way) "that there is not enough statistical evidence for more blocks." I before scaled the weights between 0 and 1. Might it be issue? Does it make sense to apply a transformation to weights (e.g. a Exponential / arcTan functions) to "stress" the differences ?

Comment: Depending on the specific method you use, you don't need to apply a scaling before clustering. You can try to use a transformation to your weights, but at some point you won't be far away from thresholding your data.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a weighted network you need to use the `weight='weight'` argument:

```
import networkx as nx
import community
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

W = np.random.rand(15,15)
np.fill_diagonal(W,0.0)

G = nx.from_numpy_array(W)
louvain_partition = community.best_partition(G, weight='weight')
modularity2 = community.modularity(louvain_partition, G, weight='weight')
print("The modularity Q based on networkx is {}".format(modularity2))
```

The modularity Q based on networkx is 0.0849022950503318